MYSQL keyring contents deletion or addition in mysql community version
I recently came to discover keyring file in mysql community version. I tried to delete the contents of the file and then run mysql the contents of my encrypted table were not retrieved. Is there any way to recover this keyring file in case of deletion or modification of file content.
Im wokring with mysql 8.0.36 on ubuntu.
Thanks
MYSQL keyring docuemntation on offcial website.

Sure, restore from your backup.
